# How to bind button content to the static readonly field

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bind

I have a class `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace HomeSecurity {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public static readonly string START = "start", RESET = "RESET";
     .....
}
```

There is a button in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Button x:Name="AcceptCamerasButton"  Content="{x:Static local:MainWindow.START}" Grid.Row="1" Click="AcceptCamerasButton_Click"></Button>
```

How to set content of  that button to `MainWindow.Start`? Current version does not work.

**EDIT:**
I have declared:

```
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HomeSecurity"
```

but still when I use:

```
 <Button x:Name="AcceptCamerasButton"  Content="{x:Static local:MainWindow.START}" Grid.Row="1" Click="AcceptCamerasButton_Click"></Button>
```

I get:

```
Error   1   The member "START" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind to fields. Bindings only work on properties. So you can either change the definition of `START` to a property, or create a property wrapper that returns the value of `START` and bind to that instead.

```
public static string START
{ 
   get { return "start"}
}

public static string RESET
{ 
   get { return "RESET"; }
}
```

Or, if you prefer to keep the readonly backing field:

```
private static readonly string startField = "start";

public static string START
{ 
   get { return startField}
}
```

Also, I'm assuming that you've already done this, but I'm including this anyway, make sure you include the namespace declaration in the XAML file for the `local` namespace to point to the local assembly and appropriate namespace.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectAssemblyName..."
```

Comment: How to define readonly static property. Could you declare and initilize START property?

Comment: @Yoda yes, of course. I've just updated the answer with relevant details

Comment: Could you please see my edited original post please?

Comment: Also: Error 2 The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item

Comment: Removed readonly.. Works like a charm but I would like to have constants there.

Comment: @Yoda, bindings don't work with fields as I said. But logically a constant is basically something that doesn't change. A property that only has a getter as I showed in the example code fits that bill nicely in my mind. However, you can also keep the constant and just wrap that with a get-only property.